# PHP case insensitive search through text file

Tags: javascript, php, search, case-insensitive

I have this .php file that searches for text from a .txt file and compares it to what the user has typed in. I'm not sure how to make it do a case insensitive search of the .txt file.

```
<?php
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $text = file_get_contents('name_list.txt');
  $lines = explode("\n", $text);
  if(in_array($_POST['search'], $lines)){
      echo stristr($search, " is compatible!");
  } else {
      echo stristr($search, " is not compatible!");
  }
?>
```

Here is the javascript it is linked to:

```
$(function() {

        $(".search_button").click(function() {
            var searchString = $("#search_box").val();
            var data = 'search='+ searchString;

            if(searchString) {
                // ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "do_search.php",
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function(html) {
                        $("#results").html(''); 
                        $("#searchresults").show();
                        $(".word").html(searchString);
                   },
                   success: function(html){
                        $("#results").show();
                        $("#results").append(html);
                  }
                });    
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Any help/comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would compare the uncapitalised version of the search and the text files:

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search_lower = strtolower($search); // make the search lowercase
$text = file_get_contents('name_list.txt');
$text = strtolower($text); // make the text lowercase
$lines = explode("\n", $text);

if(in_array($search_lower, $lines)){
    echo $search . " is compatible!";
} else {
    echo $search . " is not compatible!";
}
```

Comment: The .txt file has names such as 'Sam' or 'Smith'. Currently, if you input 'Sam Smith' into the search bar, it returns false even though both 'Sam' and 'Smith' are individually in the .txt file, but on different lines. Any idea how I could make it compatible with surnames? e.g. return true if the input was 'Sam Smith', or false if input was '[name_in_file] [name_not_in_file]'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$text = file_get_contents('name_list.txt');

if(preg_match('#'.$search.'#i', $text)){
    echo $search . " is compatible!";
} else {
    echo $search . " is not compatible!";
}
```

The 'i' flag after the expression delimiter indicates a case insensitive matching.

Comment: This will match substrings too, not only lines. Like `dont` in `IDontKnow`.